# insert method of C++ template class

Tags: c++, templates, struct

Below is what I have implemented so far. When debugging the following code after I execute 
"n = new node(val, NULL, NULL);" in the insert method and leave the insert method, the "val" is NOT saved in the root node once I leave the method and I do not understand why.

```
// Creates an empty binary tree
template<class T> binTree<T>::binTree() {
    root = NULL;
}

template<class T> void binTree<T>::insert(T val) {
    insert(val, root);
}

template<class T> void binTree<T>::insert(T val, node* n) {
    if (n == NULL) {
        n = new node(val, NULL, NULL); // <=============Not actually storing the value into the node after this method is done
    } else if (val < n->val) {
        if (n->left == NULL) {
            n->left = new node(val, NULL, NULL);
        } else {
            insert(val, n->left);
        }
    } else if (val > n->val) {
        if (n->right == NULL) {
            n->right = new node(val, NULL, NULL);
        } else {
            insert(val, n->right);
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my private struct in the header file:

```
private:
    struct node {
        T val;
        node* left;
        node* right;

        node(T v, node* l, node* r) :
                val(v), left(l), right(r) {
        }
    };

    void destruct(node* n);
    void insert(T val, node* n);
    T find(T val, node* n) const;
    T remove(T val, node* n, node* parent);

    node* root;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are accepting the pointer by value, so you are only modifying the local variable `n`, changes to which are lost when the function returns.

Maybe you meant to take `n` by reference, like `node*& n`? This means that changes to `n` inside the function will affect the parameter you pass into the function.